# How to export all attribute xpath value

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to get the img url of a html file using XPath

For example :

My XPath Select

> //div[contains(@class,'content')]/p//@src

The result is :

```
<div class="entry-content clearfix single-post-content" style="background-color: transparent;">
<p style="background-color: transparent;">
    <img src="https://example.com/0.jpg" alt="example" style="background-color: transparent;">
    <img src="https://example.com/1.jpg" alt="example">
    <img src="https://example.com/2.jpg" alt="example">
    <img src="https://example.com/3.jpg" alt="example">
    </p>
```

And i want to store the text so i use

> string(//div[contains(@class,'content')]/p//@src)

But the result show me only

> https://example.com/0.jpg

Is there any way i can get all the URL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your `XPath` to [return list of strings](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22entry-content%20clearfix%20single-post-content%22%20style%3D%22background-color%3A%20transparent%3B%22%3E%0A%3Cp%20style%3D%22background-color%3A%20transparent%3B%22%3E%0A%20%3Cimg%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F0.jpg%22%20alt%3D%22example%22%20style%3D%22background-color%3A%20transparent%3B%22%3E%3C%2Fimg%3E%0A%20%3Cimg%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F1.jpg%22%20alt%3D%22example%22%3E%0A%20%3Cimg%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F2.jpg%22%20alt%3D%22example%22%3E%0A%20%3Cimg%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F3.jpg%22%20alt%3D%22example%22%3E%0A%20%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E&=&extract=%2F%2Fdiv[contains(%40class%2C'content')]%2F%2Fimg%2Fstring(%40src)&=string&input-format=html&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath2), try

```
//div[contains(@class,'content')]//img/string(@src)
```

Comment: Sorry,but that's is not a valid XPath expression :(

Comment: Your code seems working fine on your comment links ,but i don't know why its not working for me !? The console tell me "that's is not a valid XPath expression"

Comment: Does this `//div[contains(@class,'content')]//img/@src/string()` works or gives the same result?

Comment: Well,i'm trying to use it in firepath addons of firefox,still not working !